# MutationObserver not showing all mutations?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a 3rd-party script that loads a photo gallery on my page with the images coming from off-site.

My page starts as empty:

```
  <div class="container-fluid" id="cincopa">

  </div>
```

The 3rd-party script then adds other stuff (like the frame of the photo gallery):

```
      <div class="container-fluid" id="cincopa">
        <div id="cp_widget_38cc1320-f4a4-407a-a80e-1747bd339b64">

        </div>
      </div>
```

Then finally the images load:

```
      <div class="container-fluid" id="cincopa">
        <div id="cp_widget_38cc1320-f4a4-407a-a80e-1747bd339b64">
          <div class="galleria_images">
            <div class="galleria_image">SomeImage</div>
            <div class="galleria_image">SomeImage</div>
            <div class="galleria_image">SomeImage</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I want to:

- display a loading animation
- set a `MutationObserver` on `$('#cincopa')`
- when it detects that `$('.galleria_image')` has been created, it means images have been loaded, so I can
- remove the loading animation

Code:

```
var target = document.querySelector('#cincopa');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    console.log(mutations);
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      console.log(mutation.type);
    }); 
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// start the observer, pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```

The problem is that the `MutationObserver` only console logs one mutation and the `MutationRecord` only has one mutation in its array. I would expect numerous mutations as the 3rd-party script creates DOM elements.

Am I misunderstanding how `MutationObserver` works?

***Here's the solution***

```
// This is MeteorJS creating the loading spinning thing
var loadingView = Blaze.render(Template.loading, $('#cincopa')[0]);

// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('#cincopa');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {

  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if(mutation.target.className === "galleria_image"){
        // a image has been loaded, so remove the loading spinner and 
        // kill the observer
        Blaze.remove(loadingView);
        observer.disconnect();
    }
  }); 

});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true, subtree: true };

// start the observer, pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```

***Updated Solution***

`.forEach` is dumb and doesn't have a good way to break out of the loop, which meant that I was getting multiple commands to `Blaze.remove()` and `observer.disconnect()`, even after `.galleria_image` had been found.

So I used `underscore` instead:

```
// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {

  var loaded = _.find(mutations, function(mutation){ 
    console.log("observer running");
    return mutation.target.className === "galleria-image";
  });

  if(loaded){
    Blaze.remove(loadingView);
    observer.disconnect();
    console.log("observer stopped");
  };

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an option to allow you to do exactly what you want: observe the subtree of an element. Just add [`subtree: true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#MutationObserverInit) to your `config` for the `MutationObserver`.

```
// ...
// In this case case only these two are needed, I believe.
var config = {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
};
// ...observe
```

This should allow you to figure when `.gallaria_images` has been inserted. As a side note, you (OP) should also double check that images are loaded when that happens.

Comment: Thanks! All good and OP updated with solution. I originally thought only `childList` was required.